# How to backup live mysql database?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5, mysqldump, backup

I have 12 GB MySQL InnoDB Database with around 800 queries per second. No sooner I start 'mysqldump' over it to make backup I start getting '503' on my website.

How do I make backup of my live database without affecting the site performance?

Comment: What options did you use for mysqldump ?

Comment: none, 'mysqldump databasename > dump.sql'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try the following command since the database size is not small:

```
mysqldump -u USER -p --single-transaction --quick --lock-tables=false --all-databases (or) DATABASE | gzip > OUTPUT.gz
```

Comment: `--single-transaction` disables `--lock-tables`, so no need for `--lock-tables=false` (See http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/60145/877)

Comment: And what does --quick do?

Comment: @dragosrsupercool this is a quot from MySQL website : --quick:This option is useful for dumping large tables. It forces mysqldump to retrieve rows for a table from the server a row at a time rather than retrieving the entire row set and buffering it in memory before writing it out.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA In-fact I referred to the following website  t that describe why use (--lock-tables=false) or (--skip-lock-tables) http://aaronbonner.io/post/5662779872/optimising-backups-with-mysql 
please advise thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You need to use Percona XtraBackup tool. It works like a charm for huge datasets and doesn't interrupt MySQL operations. http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.2/innobackupex/creating_a_backup_ibk.html There are some tricks but it's worth it.

Comment: All should keep in mind that mysqldump can catch a snapshot from the start of the backup whereas Percona XtraBackup catches snapshot from the completion of the backup.

Answer (score 4):

You should use Percona Toolkit to backup database to prevent from blocking database:

```
sudo innobackupex --user=root --password=rootPASSWORD --host localhost /tmp/
sudo innobackupex --apply-log --use-memory=2G /tmp/$TIMESTAMP/
```

You need enough disk space in `/tmp`. Once you finish it, you can copy entire directory to another server.

In `xtrabackup_binlog_info`, there is replication information. (it is useful if you need to setup slave replication)

Comment: +1 for the extra info. All should keep in mind that mysqldump can catch a snapshot from the start of the backup whereas Percona XtraBackup catches snapshot from the completion of the backup.

Comment: Ran out of votes. I'll upvote after 7PM EST.

Answer (score 2):

You must use [**--single-transaction**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction) option

```
mysqldump -uroot -p --single-transaction databasename > dump.sql
```

It allows for point-in-time snapshot of data. Once mysqldump starts, all the InnoDB tables will be frozen in time. Suppose you start the mysqldump at 2:30 PM and it finishes at 3:00 PM. All the InnoDB tables dumped will be from 2:30 PM. All other changes (INSERTs, UPDATEs, DELETEs) will continue with interruption and will not be included in the dump.

MyISAM would interfere with the point-in-time backup if the MyISAM tables were being updated by INSERTs, UPDATEs, or DELETEs. If the MyISAM tables were just for reads, [**--single-transaction**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction) would still be fine.

## SUGGESTION

If you have MySQL Replication set up, you could go the Slave and run this

```
mysql -uroot -p... -ANe"STOP SLAVE"
mysqldump -uroot -p --single-transaction databasename > dump.sql
mysql -uroot -p... -ANe"START SLAVE"
```

The Master wouldn't know of any backups going on.

Comment: Can you elaborate on point-in-time?

Comment: You will have data when the transaction started.

Comment: @MladenUzelac you are right, provided no MyISAM table is updated in any way.

Comment: For further clarification see my old post http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35237/how-does-mysqldump-take-place-when-there-are-more-than-one-database/35269#35269

Comment: `STOP REPLICA SQL_THREAD;`  And leave the `IO_THREAD` running.