# How to backup a replica Using mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, replication, mysqldump

From [MySQL Documents](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/8.0/en/replication-solutions-backups-mysqldump.html), and [This answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/84224/171650) they said:

> When using mysqldump, you should stop replication on the replica before starting the dump process to ensure that the dump contains a consistent set of data:

Since my DBs are big, I thought to use `--single-transaction --quick` to take a snapshot of my DBs and continue to receive data from the master.

My question is, what will happen if I do not stop the `replica` and receive new data during backup time?

**Note**: I know `--single-transaction` take a snapshot, But I want to know if my approach has any disadvantages.

Comment: "Consistent snapshot" is a current state of table(s) with undo log applied up to the moment CS has been created. If tables are modified intensively then a significant overhead (CPU/RAM/IO) can appear. You have to try it with your actual database to decide if this overhead is affordable to you.

Answer (score 0):

This will decrease the contention between the Replica's clients and the dump:

`STOP REPLICA SQL_THREAD;`  And leave the `IO_THREAD` running.

It leaves the I/O going to minimize potential loss if the Primary crashes.

If you need the Replica's clients to still hit the db, don't bother with this `STOP`.

Comment: can you please let me know why my approach is wrong, and how your approach solves this problem?

Comment: Sorry, I did intend to invalidate your answer.  I updated my Answer.